# Why is this ColorAnimation not starting?

Tags: wpf, controltemplate, togglebutton, visualstatemanager, coloranimation

I'm trying to get a ColorAnimation to occur depending on the control's state. I created a ControlTemplate for the ToggleButton that looks something like this:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="ToggleButton">
    <Border>
    <Grid>
        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroup>
             <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                  <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver">
                      <Storyboard>
                           <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ColorChangeRect" 
                               Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Rectangle.Fill).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                               To="Blue" Duration="0:0:3" />
                      </Storyboard>
                  </VisualState>
             </VisualStateGroup>
        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroup>
        <Rectangle x:Name=ColorChangeRect" Fill="Red" />
        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
    </Grid>
    </Border>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Unfortunately, nothing is occuring. I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: oh wow D: I see my problem so clearly now. I should keep a rubber duck at my desk. @_@

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups` attached property on the root element of your template, the `Border` in your code. That's where the `VisualStateManager` is getting its states from.